# Special looping for visible cells only

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below issue;

For my filtered data I want to apply the rule A2=B2, A4=B4, etc

I tried the below code, but it does not work, it takes only the first value of B2

```
Sub SpecialLoop()
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
    x = 1
    
    Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        cl = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`cl = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

try this:

`cl.Value = cl.Offset(0, 1).Value`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop at all, if you're just copying column B to column A:

```
Sub copy_visible_cells_from_B_to_A()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rng.Value = rng.Offset(, 1).Value 
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked in the opposite way. It took the values of A and replaced the values in B.

Comment: My bad! Sorry. I've fixed that now.